# Why does jQuery Validate ignore the Html input pattern?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jQuery validate to validate if an input matches the input pattern, but it looks like it doesn't check the pattern.

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="testform">
    <input id="MyInput" 
           name="MyInput"
           pattern="[A-Za-z0-9-_]"
           minlength="6"
           data-msg-pattern="Wrong input"
           data-msg-minlength="Too short"
           data-msg-required="Input required"
           required/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="AddMyInput">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#AddMyInput").click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  myvalidator = $("#testform").validate();
  if (myvalidator.form()) {
    alert("Great!"); 
  } 
});
```

Link to example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CribAd/x8g1ujyh/)

I try to limit the input to alphanumeric characters plus - and _. But it looks like the pattern is ignored by jQuery Validate, try to put 'hello guys!!' in the input field, it will alert 'Great!', but the input is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `pattern` rule is not part of this plugin.  However, you simply need to [include the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/additional-methods.js) to add it.

Your jsFiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/8mhzrdyv/](http://jsfiddle.net/8mhzrdyv/)

---

As a side-note, you should not be initializing the plugin inside of a `click` handler.   Looking at your simple demo, there is really no need for a `click` handler in the first place.  By calling `.validate()`, which initializes the plugin, the `click` event is being automatically handled by the plugin itself.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/8mhzrdyv/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/8mhzrdyv/1/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("#testform").validate();  // initialize plugin
});
```

Comment: Is it that easy? Yes it is... Thanks mate!

Comment: @CribAd, you're welcome.  Please see my edited answer.